# Camel route consuming ActiveMQ "Classic" message with unexpected delay in a random way

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-camel-3

We have an integration application based on Apache Camel and IBM MQ message broker. Part of our development work we need to be able to run this application locally on our developer laptops. The issue is that most of us have MacBook machines with Apple M1 processors and these cannot run IBM MQ message broker docker container. It seems M1 processors are not supported yet by IBM.

One solution we came up with was to fire up an EC2 in AWS have IBM MQ installed in there and open a ssh connection channel to that. Apart from the inconvenience of having to keep your EC2 compliant having one EC2 for each individual developer becomes a bit of an expense so we decided to use ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.11.1 as local message broker.

Based on some settings we configured our application to either create an ActiveMQ connection factory or an IBM MQ one and also use either an ActiveMQ or a JMS camel component which we then added to the Camel context with the same key so routes definition stays the same regardless of which message broker we use.

```
  var jmsComponent = useActiveMq ? activeMqComponent(cf) : new JmsComponent(new JmsConfiguration(cf));
  jmsComponent.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
  camelContext.addComponent(key, jmsComponent);
```

Everything works as expected and we are actually very happy with the end result. To test the functionality we used the ActiveMQ admin interface and manually injected some messages in some of our queues. In most of the cases the messages get picked up by the application instantly (as it should) but we observed that after a while it just takes forever (minutes) for a message to be picked up. We could not notice any particular pattern around this behaviour but we noticed that when starts happening it goes like this consistently.

We did not notice such a behaviour when running against an IBM MQ message broker but we cannot say it is because of ActiveMQ broker or just the ActiveMQ admin interface or the way we configured our routes. When restarting the application all messages get consumed in no time. All our routes are transacted.

I am a bit out of ideas and hopefully someone with more experience with ActiveMQ and or Camel can have some suggestions.

Initially I was using 5.16.5 which comes as a transitive dependency from `spring-boot-starter-activemq` but our CI server rejected because it has three vulnerabilities. Forcing the app to use 5.17.3 changed nothing.

**NOTE 1**

I replaced one of the Camel routes with a `@JmsListener` spring component and the random delays still happening which makes me think this issue has nothing to do with Apache Camel.

**NOTE 2**

I made the change below and it fixed the problem. The change consisted in using a fake cached connection factory with a cache size of 1. After making that change the messages were consumed off the queue as soon as they were made available with no exception. It would still be good to have an explanation about what caused the issue when cache size was 500:

```
private CachingConnectionFactory cachedConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
    var cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
    // We don't want a cached connection factory when using ActiveMQ
    // The easiest way to achieve this is without complicating too
    // much our implementation is by setting the cache size to 1
    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(useActiveMq ? 1 : 500);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setExceptionListener(e -> log.error("ErrorResponse making connection with MQ", e));
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: Have you gotten any thread dumps from the Camel application when you notice the delay? If so, could you paste that information somewhere? If not, could you?

Comment: Initially I was using 5.16.5 which comes as a transitive dependency from spring-boot-starter-activemq but our CI server rejected because it has three vulnerabilities. Forcing the app to use 5.17.3 changed nothing

Comment: What about thread dumps which I asked about previously?

Comment: Have you tried using ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: In the web console it displays version 5.11.1 for the actual activemq broker. I assume this was the latest one available in our company repository. No I haven't tried artemis because I never used it before and I thought it would be too much of a big change. I can give it a try assuming that image is available on our company repository

Comment: Any feedback on the thread dumps?

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.11.1 is over 7 years old now. There's been over 50 releases since then. I strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest version or try ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Changing to ActiveMQ 5.17.3 which is the latest changed nothing. My feeling is that is not ActiveMQ to blame here but on the other hand why we did not notice this behaviour with  IBM MQ

Comment: Why do you feel ActiveMQ is not to blame? Is there some other difference in the two tests you're running?

Comment: No, there is absolutely no difference in the way we run the application. It is just a flag we use saying use IBM MQ or ActiveMQ. Then depending on this flag we create a different `ConnectionFactory` instance. When I said net ActiveMQ is to blame I was referring that something might not be done correctly in our configuration which make ActiveMQ behave that way whereas IBM MQ does not care. See my `NOTE 2` in my question. I done that change after google told me not to use a cached connection factory when using XA. That fixed the issue but I still don't have a clear explanation of the cause